# coefficients for formula

Tags: r, regression-coefficients

This is the formula I'm using

Call:

```
lm(formula = kg ~ ft * temp)
```

and the coefficients

```
coef(fit)
          (Intercept)                    ft                  temp               ft:temp 
 3.02787289439677e+03 -7.68497422047300e-02 -9.10978930930598e+00  9.14330790288404e-05
```

Now I need this formula and the coefficients in a different program.
I understand the `intercept`, `ft`, `temp` but not `ft:temp`. How does that fit in the formula?
Thanks for any help

Comment: That is the interaction term. The formula is: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 ft + \beta_2 temp + \beta_3 ft*temp$ If you do not need it, replace the * with + in your formula statement.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight +1 but I think the use of $ft*temp$ in the last term of your explanation of the meaning of `ft * temp` may be confusing (though the distinction is clear enough if you already get what's going on). In case that does lead to some confusion for beginner: - that last term in Penguin_Knight's formula means $\text{ft}\times\text{temp}$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I interpret the results of a regression which involves interaction terms?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41379/how-do-i-interpret-the-results-of-a-regression-which-involves-interaction-terms)

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for pointing that out. I agree with your change.