# How to interpret regression estimates

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction, interpretation

I am studying the effect a certain chemical and age on an outcome.  As variables, `age` is a factor of with levels 1, 2, and 3 and `covar1` is continuous.

After fitting the model

```
mod1 <- glm(out1 ~ covar1*age, family=poisson, data=df)
```

The estimates are

```
Parametric coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value      Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -0.6236832  0.1037201  -6.013 0.00000000185 ***
covar1          0.0204307  0.0101802   2.007        0.0448 *  
age2            1.2523312  0.0649721  19.275       < 2e-16 ***
age3            0.8373618  0.0673236  12.438       < 2e-16 ***
covar1:age2    -0.0145580  0.0098667  -1.475        0.1401    
covar1:age3     0.0109891  0.0101829   1.079        0.2805    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

How do I interpret the effects of `covar1` and `age` on my outcome?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58973/interpretation-of-the-ols-regression-coefficient-of-a-proportion-dependent-and-i is a duplicate of this question (but has no answers to date).  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41379/how-do-i-interpret-the-results-of-a-regression-which-involves-interaction-terms asks exactly the same question but does not stipulate that one of the variables is categorical.  Nevertheless, its answer is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Covar1 has a positive effect on the outcome (coefficient is significatively different from zero and positive). Age2 and age3 have a positive and significant effect on the outcome (when compared to the baseline). age2 and age3 are probably equivalent with respect to their effect on the outcome since their confidence overlaps (+- 2se) Interaction is not significant.

Comment: would had that poisson uses a log link, so you want to take that into account when interpreting coefficients.

Comment: @Giorgio, Thank you for your clarification. Could you explain the following? For which group does the estimate of 0.0204307 for covar1 represent? Is it an overall estimate for all in the study population or only for age1? And what is the combined effect of covar1 and age1? Many thanks

Comment: 0.0204307=an overall estimate for all in the study population;  what is the combined effect of covar1 and age1= -0.6236832+0.0204307*covar1 (since age1 is the base level, so its effect included in constant -0.62 and not in any interaction).